# При запросе предлагает добавить представления в группировку

Tags: sql-server, выборка

Столбец "`Goods.RetailPrice`" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении `GROUP BY`.

Столбец "`Sales.Count`" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении `GROUP BY`.

Вот код:

```
SELECT (Sum(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count) * dbo.GetDiscount(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count)/100) as Results
FROM Sales, Goods
WHERE Sales.NameID = Goods.id AND Sales.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Почему MS SQL ругается на этот код?

Comment: @T2skler, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что он не знает, что вы имеете в виду. Я вот, например, тоже не понимаю: вы умножаете сумму по всем документам за период на скидку, определяемую для какой-то одной позиции. Только вот для какой из множества позиций вы считаете скидку - та еще загадка.

Comment: Мне нужно определить сумму общей скидки по всем продажам за месяц. Как это можно сделать? GetDiscount возвращает INT - скидка в процентах.

Comment: (Sum(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count) /100. * dbo.GetDiscount(Sum(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count))) as Results

Comment: И да, об этом не прилично говорить, но я все же скажу: в течение месяца цена могла меняться.

Comment: Для курсача всё фиксированно)) Большое спасибо) Только почему-то не так считает, например, с 14950 со скидкой в 2 процента должен писать 299, а выводит 319. Понятно, за последний месяц куплены два товара, один 14950, а второй 1000, он высчитывает 2% и применяет эту скидку для обоих товаров. Как просуммировать их отдельно? Необходимо по каждой сделке, суммировать скидку отдельно. Т.е. в первой покупке выходит 2%, т.к. > 10000, а во второй 0%

Comment: (Sum(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count /100. *  dbo.GetDiscount(Goods.RetailPrice * Sales.Count))) as Results